# Matplotlib does not plot anything when running other process

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I wrote a script that used python threads like this

```
class Viewer:
    def __init__(self):
        _, self.ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        self.ax.set_ylim((-self.ax_lim, self.ax_lim))
        self.ax.set_xlim((-self.ax_lim, self.ax_lim))
        self.ax.set_aspect('equal')
        self.ax.grid()
        self.textvar = self.ax.text(-self.ax_lim-10, -self.ax_lim-10, '0.0')
        
        self.i=0

        #The threaded part
        x = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_function, args=(1,))
        x.start()
        plt.show()

    def thread_function(self,name):
        while(self.i<5000):
            #Do some plotting here
            self.i+=1
            #plt.pause(0.01) 
            #here remove the plotting
```

When I run it I could see the plot in the matplotlib window and the plotting got refreshed every time.
However using python threads made it *very slow*

So instead using the following [article on python multithreading](https://blog.devgenius.io/why-is-multi-threaded-python-so-slow-f032757f72dc) I changed this to multiprocesses like

```
from multiprocessing import Process    
class Viewer:
    def __init__(self):
        _, self.ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        self.ax.set_ylim((-self.ax_lim, self.ax_lim))
        self.ax.set_xlim((-self.ax_lim, self.ax_lim))
        self.ax.set_aspect('equal')
        self.ax.grid()
        self.textvar = self.ax.text(-self.ax_lim-10, -self.ax_lim-10, '0.0')

        self.i=0

        #The threaded part
        
        x=Process(target=self.thread_function,args=(1,))
        x.start()
        plt.show()

    def thread_function(self,name):
        while(self.i<5000):
            #Do some plotting here
            self.i+=1
            #plt.pause(0.01) ##<--- this generates an error
            time.sleep(0.01)
            #here remove the plotting
```

And I got two things:

1. Using `plt.pause` generates an error

   [xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
   [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
   [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
   python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:259: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
   XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
   after 348 requests (348 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
   Aborted (core dumped)
2. However replacing this by `time.sleep(0.01)` does not generate the eror. However ***Nothing gets plotted***

So I am wondering why the plots worked with threads (although slow) but not with multiprocess?

Comment: which os are you on?

Comment: @Charchit  linux

Comment: You almost certainly are not going to get away with running the default Matplotlib event loop and spawning threads: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq/howto_faq.html#work-with-threads